# how to upload files using Apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, contentdocument, files

I am creating a VF page to upload files to to the Files related list of an object :

[image]

I found out that files object is ContentDocument object. I am figuring out how I can create this ContentDocument object. Something like:

```
ContentDocument  cd = new ContentDocument (title='',parentid='',body)
```

Seems like this in not the approach. How can I add the file select by the user . I have a `inputfile` tag in my VF page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ContentDocument object ***does not allow insert DML*** operation in Salesforce, so we can upload it through the **ContentVersion** object, without ContentDocumentId. 
After DML on ContentVersion a new version of ContentDocument will be created for us in salesforce.

The easiest way to do this is using inputFile and assign it to ContentVersion instance. Like this:

```
<apex:page controller="ContentController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" />
    <apex:commandbutton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Class:**

```
public class ContentController {
    public blob file { get; set; }

    public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'testing upload';
        v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
        insert v;
        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }
}
```

If you want to share the ContentVersion file then after insert DML query the ContentDocumentId from inserted ContentVersion and use ContentDocumentLink to create association between Record and ContentVersion uploaded file.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Use "**LinkedEntityId**" field to place the record id to which this file will be associated.

Note: **LinkedEntityId** - Can include Chatter users, groups, records (any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects), and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

hope this helps and mark this as answer if does. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. How do I relate to the record for which I am attaching the file?

Comment: Do you want to upload file for records? Like notes and attachment?

Comment: Yes exactly! Wish to do like that

Comment: Edited the original answer with more info. if you want to upload in Notes And Attachment then use Attachment object instead of ContentVersion.

Comment: I am struggling uploading file in contentVersion using lightning component. Can any one please guide me with this. Refer to below link for details :  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/uploading-file-in-contentversion-using-lightning-component

Comment: Can we make the document public after inserting using code ?

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to insert ContentVersion and attach it to Record in one SOQL.

```
<apex:page controller="ContentController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" />
        <apex:commandbutton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class ContentController {
    public blob file { get; set; }

    public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'testing upload';
        v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
        v.FirstPublishLocationId = parentObj.Id; //similar to parentid
        insert v;
        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much simpler, and deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Glad, I am able to help. Thanks for your support @MatthewSouther.