# Getting Unrecognized symbol '\', which is not a valid Apex identifier Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

am try to Upload Image from my phone camera but am getting Unrecognized symbol '\', which is not a valid Apex identifier Error.

this is my Apex Code:

```
public class FeedbackController {


public FeedbackFrom__c Fed {
  get { 
    if(Fed== null) 
        Fed = new FeedbackFrom__c();
    return Fed; 

   set;
  }

     public Registration__c Reg {
     get { 
    if(Reg== null) 
        Reg = new Registration__c();
    return Reg; 
      }
   set;
     }
  public ContentVersion cont {get;set;}
  public PageReference Register() {
  return Page.Registrationpage;
  }
  public PageReference Login() {
  return Page.Taskpage;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire() {
  return Page.Taskpage1;
  }    

  public PageReference Questionnaire1() {
  return Page.Taskpage2;
  }

  public PageReference Questionnaire2() {
  return Page.Taskpage3;
  }

  public PageReference Questionnaire3() {
  return Page.Taskpage4;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire4() {
  return Page.Taskpage5;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire5() {
  return Page.Taskpage6;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire6() {
  return Page.Taskpage7;
 }
  public PageReference Questionnaire7() {
  return Page.Taskpage8;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire8() {
  return Page.Taskpage9;
 }
  public PageReference Questionnaire9() {
  return Page.Taskpage10;
  }
  public PageReference Questionnaire10() {
  return Page.FinalPage;
 }
   public  PageReference Profilesetting(){
   system.debug('test');
   PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/00e?
  setupid=EnhancedProfiles&retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DUsers'); 
  pr.setRedirect(true);
  return pr;
 }
 public  PageReference Logout(){
 system.debug('test');
 PageReference pr = new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp'); 
 pr.setRedirect(true);
 return pr;
}
public PageReference Yes() {
return Page.Taskpage1;
}
public PageReference save() {
 if(Fed== null) Fed = new FeedbackFrom__c();
 Fed.Registered_Email__c = Reg.Email_id__c;
 Insert fed;

 if(Reg== null) Reg = new Registration__c();
  Insert Reg;

 try{
        cont.C:\Users\andrew.xavier\Desktop\Sfdc Document = 
       cont.title;//Here Am Geeting Error
        cont.Origin = 'H';
        insert cont;    
        return new PageReference('/'+cont.id);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('@@'+ ex.getMessage());
    } 

  PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
  FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);

  return FeedbackPage;
 }

 }
```

Comment: what is this `cont.C:\Users\andrew.xavier\Desktop\Sfdc Document = 
       cont.title;` ?

Comment: My File Path name

Comment: you can't use like this.  you have to use visualforce apex:inputField to upload a  file. check this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131100/18731